# Getting java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'December 05, 2020 at 10:00:00 AM PDT' could not be parsed at index 17

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

I am trying to run the below code in IntelliJ IDE and getting the parsing exception whereas the code works on the online Java Compiler. Can somebody please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String slot = "December 05, 2020 at 10:00:00 AM PDT";
      String locale = "en-US";
      String timezone = "America/Los_Angeles";
      long epoch = convertDateToLong(slot, locale, timezone);
      System.out.println(epoch);
    }
    
    private static long convertDateToLong (String dateTimeString, String locale, String timezone) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timezone);
        String offsetId = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.of(timezone)).getOffset().toString();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG).withZone(zoneId).withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(locale));
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
        long epoch = localDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of(offsetId));
        return epoch * 1000;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly a locale issue. Try *formatting* a `ZonedDateTime` with the formatter instead. That way you know what it expects.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Sweeper. Not sure if the issue is locale then why it's working on the online compiler. Can you please suggest what type of ZonedDateTime formatter I can use?

Comment: You could write a custom one: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, uuuu 'at' hh:mm:ss a z", Locale.ENGLISH)` for example… Maybe even try `Locale.US`, too. Or you just use the one you have in the method that sometimes fails.

Comment: Your format actually wants "2023 Jun 28 04:33:38 PDT" or the like. But your datetime string contains the word "at" for some reason. Also your locale string is wrong. It should be `en_US`. You have `en-US`

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Also, it works without any issue with IntelliJ in my system. Try upgrading your IntelliJ version.

Comment: @g00se - There is no problem with `en-US`. Remember `en-US` denotes the language while `en_US` denotes a locale. So, you can print `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US").getDisplayLanguage()` to understand the difference. You can further check the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage--).

Comment: *Remember en-US denotes the language* Right, thanks